# Share image and text to whatsapp in single share in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, share, swift4, whatsapp

Could anyone suggest me how to share image with text to whatsaap or any alternative for the same.I have tried it using UIActivityViewController but its possible to share image+text simultaneously on mail bt not on whatsaap .
Help will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

code is as follows:

```
let textToShare = "Hello world" 
let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"https://www.apple.com/")
let img = UIImage(named:"BookImg")

let shareall = [img!,textToShare,myWebsite!] as [Any]

let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareall, applicationActivities: nil)

vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: as a alternative to above, can anyone please tell me how to add caption to image so that i can share image+text on whatsaap?

Comment: this may be help you https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: This question has been asked many times on SO. You can share text OR an image to WhatsApp (and Facebook and Messenger), but not both together.

Comment: @dev Please ask about adding a caption to an image as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't post Images and Text together on WhatsApp. However, you can post one at a time. As Whatsapp does not provide any API you can add captions and post images with text.

For your reference , WhatsApp:

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

An easy alternative is handing the image part from your server side. Host it and share the link along with the caption. the image will be shown automatically through the URL you are sharing.
It will appear like below,

SS: https://ibb.co/7tpqm8S